# Proper Install of Iron Handrail outside

Tags: installation, stairs, handrail

I have a question installing a iron handrail for some stairs outside of my house. I don't have a wide enough walk way to surface mount the handrail to the level surface of the stairs and walk way so I have opted to put in concrete piers, 6 inches in diameter, down below frost level to embed the posts to the handrail. There are only two steps at this entrance, so it's a very short rail. The handrail's two balusters are one inch square.

My question is, am I overdoing this and is there a simpler/better way? Do I need concrete piers down below frost for something as 'simple' as a free standing handrail ?

Edit: Additional Details;

Here is the area in question.  The iron handrail would be installed on the right hand side, nearer the house.  [image: Side entrance, location of handrail installation]

This is the schematic of the iron handrail its self with it's one inch iron posts.

[image: Schematic of iron handrail being installed]

Comment: Can you tell us more about the stairs? Wood? Concrete? Metal? If you put a link to a picture in comments, someone can incorporate that into your question.

Comment: The potential leverage force on a freestanding balustrade as pictured means it will need phenomenally strong foundations. It is a shame you can't find a design where one end attaches to the house wall. This would mean much lighter foundations.